# how to get all mimeparts in MimeMessage?

Tags: java, mime-message

I've MimeMessage Object and somehow I want to get all **MimeParts** from it.

Comment: for 4 questions you accepted no answer. Improve that

Answer (score 0):

`javax.mail.interntet.MimeMessage` implements interface `javax.mail.interntet.MimePart`, soe once you have an object you can call its methods including those defined in MimePart.

Message can be retrieved using `MessageContext.getMessage()`